# How to calculate this limit to $\pi$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, substitution

I need help calculating this limit:

$$ \lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\cos2x+2(\pi-x)\sin x-1}{(\cos2x+\cos x)^2}  $$
I tried to use L'Hospital's rule, but didn't get any result.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Just a minor remark on terminology: limits are *computed/calculated*; riddles/problems/equations are *solved* (for a variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=t+\pi$.

Thus, $$ \lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\cos2x+2(\pi-x)\sin x-1}{(\cos2x+\cos x)^2}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos2t+2t\sin{t}-1}{(\cos2t-\cos{t})^2}=$$
$$=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{2t\sin{t}-2\sin^2t}{(1-\cos{t})^2(2\cos{t}+1)^2}=\frac{2}{9}\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t\sin{t}-\sin^2t}{4\sin^4\frac{t}{2}}=$$
$$=\frac{8}{9}\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t\sin{t}-\sin^2{t}}{t^4}=\frac{8}{9}\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t-\sin{t}}{t^3}=$$
$$=\frac{8}{9}\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos{t}}{3t^2}=\frac{8}{9}\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{2\sin^2\frac{t}{2}}{3t^2}=\frac{8}{9}\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{2\cdot\frac{t^2}{4}}{3t^2}=\frac{4}{27}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: breaks it like this 
$$\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\cos2x+2(\pi-x)\sin x-1}{(\cos2x+\cos x)^2} \\=\lim_{x\to \pi}\left(\frac{\cos2x-1}{(\pi-x)^2 }+2\frac{\sin x}{(\pi-x)}\right)\cdot\lim_{x\to \pi}\left(\frac{\pi-x}{\cos2x+\cos x}\right)^2$$

Then use the definition of derivative of a function at $x=\pi.$